# Probability (Using a pack of cards with an unknown amount n)

Tags: probability

I am perplexed with how to start the following question, where a pack contains n cards labelled 1,2,3,...,n (one number on each card). Then the cards are chosen randomly and dealt out.
I have to (a) Find the probability that the second chosen card shows a larger number than the ﬁrst, and then (b) Find the probability that the second card shows 3, given that the second card shows a larger number than the ﬁrst.

Comment: What's more likely; the second card is larger than the first, or the first card is larger than the second?

Comment: Do you know how to answer the questions if the value of $n$ was given?  For example, could you answer if we were using a standard deck of $52$ cards?  Do the calculations *the exact same way here* with the only exception that instead of using $52,51,50$, you should use $n,n-1,n-2$.  Don't let the fact that you don't know the value of $n$ scare you!  $n$ is just a number, no different than $52$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) if the 1st card is 1, the possible number of options for the 2nd card is n-1 (as all the numbers 2,3,4..., n are greater than 1) similarly if the 1st card is 2,# of options for 2nd is n-1.So probability of 2nd card being greater than 1st card is

=1/n * n-1/n-1 + 1/n * n-2/n-1 +...........+1/n * 1/n-1 + 1/n * 0/n-1

=n*(n-1)/2*n*n-1

=1/2